# How do I get Plone to read my pythonrc?

Tags: python, plone, readline

I am using the [collective.python](https://github.com/collective/buildout.python) buildout.

I have the following `.pythonrc` (configured with `export PYTHONSTARTUP=~/.pythonrc`):

```
import readline
import rlcompleter
readline.parse_and_bind('tab: complete')
```

When I run `Python` in the shell, tab completion works. When I run `Plone` in debug mode it does not. Unless, I paste the contents of my `.pythonrc` into the Plone debug Python prompt. What am I missing here?

**Note**: Pasting the contents of my .pythonrc only works when I install Plone via `python bootstrap.py` (i.e. bootstrapping Plone buildout with `collective.python` Python). If I install Plone inside a `virtualenv`, nothing works. But at least in that scenario, the missing functionality makes sense to me (i.e. something is probably missing from the `virtualenv` that is required to make tab completion work.)

Comment: the module `site` is always loaded - maybe you can adapt it for plone

Comment: CAn you recommend any .pythonrc tricks that should go to developer manual debugging section?

Comment: Other than readline for tab completion, you mean? There is also a .pdbrc IIRC

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The instance controller uses two command-line switches; `-i` for interactive mode, and `-c` to  load the Zope configuration and set up the `app` variable. The `-c` switch is what disables the `PYTHONSTARTUP` environment variable.

You *could* modify the `plone.recipe.zope2instance` package to run the script anyway.

In `plone.recipe.zope2instance`, find the `plone/recipe/zope2instance/ctl.py` file, alter the `do_debug()` method to:

```
def do_debug(self, arg):
    interactive_startup = ("import os;"
        "os.path.exists(os.environ.get('PYTHONSTARTUP', '')) "
        "and execfile(os.environ['PYTHONSTARTUP']); del os;"
        'import Zope2; app=Zope2.app()')
    cmdline = self.get_startup_cmd(self.options.python,
                                   interactive_startup,
                                   pyflags = '-i', )
```

In fact, I like the idea of supporting `PYTHONSTARTUP` so much I committed that change to the recipe already, see [rev 536f8fc1c4](https://github.com/plone/plone.recipe.zope2instance/commit/537f8fc1c4a006955c90e4f227eceecd36ca6c47)!

Answer (score 1):

I do `import user`.  This reads `~/.pythonrc.py`.  Note the .py extension.  I have set that file as my `PYTHONSTARTUP`

I'll paste that file for good measure.  I have cobbled it together a few years ago.  Not sure if it is still the best, as I see comments about 2006 and python2.3.  It does the trick though.

```
$ cat ~/.pythonrc.py 
# See http://blog.partecs.com/2006/02/27/source-inspector/
#import pydoc
import inspect
import rlcompleter, readline

readline.parse_and_bind('tab: complete')

# def source(obj):
#     """source of the obj."""
#     try:
#         pydoc.pipepager(inspect.getsource(obj), 'less')
#     except IOError:
#         pass

# From /usr/local/lib/python2.3/user.py
import os
home = os.curdir                        # Default
if 'HOME' in os.environ:
    home = os.environ['HOME']
elif os.name == 'posix':
    home = os.path.expanduser("~/")
# Make sure home always ends with a directory separator:
home = os.path.realpath(home) + os.sep

# From http://wiki.python.org/moin/PdbRcIdea
# Command line history:
histfile = home + '.pyhist'
try:
    readline.read_history_file(histfile)
except IOError:
    pass
import atexit
atexit.register(readline.write_history_file, histfile)
readline.set_history_length(200)

# Cleanup namespace
# del atexit
# del home
# del histfile
# del os
# del readline
# del rlcompleter
```